# Develop Friendships or HasMany Through First?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, agile

I'm new to agile development and rails and I'm trying to think through what my logical next step is for my app.

Currently I have an app that has events and it has users. Users can follow one another, but you don't need to approve that relationship (it's like twitter right now).

My big ticket items:

1. I want a friendship model that requires approval - thinking I'll use the amistad gem for this(?)
2. I want to be able to add users to events. So users will have a many-to-many relationship with events. A user will own the event and can attach users to it.

Which should come next. #2 seems like the easier step to me at this point. But eventually I will want to only allow you to add "friends" to your events. So in that case should I develop the friendship part first or will it likely be very easy to add that into my validations as a third iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If allowing to only add friends to events is your final goal, then I'd develop friendships first.

When you will begin creating UI for adding users to events, then you'll just use `.friends` getter of a `User` object. No need to implement logic of fetching N random users (that you will throw away later anyway).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Friendshis first makes sense - was just trying to go for the lower hanging fruit I guess.